# Nest js dependency injection is not working

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

Am working on a NestJS project. The aim of this project is to list the s3 buckets.
I am using `aws-sdk`  for `aws` support. Here am using the code. The issue is in my `AWSService.ts file`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

@Injectable()
export class AWSService {
  constructor(private readonly s3: S3) {}

  async listBuckets(): Promise<S3.Buckets> {
    const response = await this.s3.listBuckets().promise();
    return response.Buckets || [];
  }
}
```

This code will return the following error

```
[Nest] 26352  - 08/01/2023, 3:36:41 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 26352  - 08/01/2023, 3:36:41 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AWSService (?). Please make sure that the argument function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } at index [0] is available in the AWSModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AWSModule a valid NestJS module?
- If function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } is a provider, is it part of the current AWSModule?
- If function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AWSModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AWSService (?). Please make sure that the argument function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } at index [0] is available in the AWSModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AWSModule a valid NestJS module?
- If function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } is a provider, is it part of the current AWSModule?
- If function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AWSModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing function() {
        if (klass !== Object) {
          return klass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      } */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:247:19)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:200:33)
    at resolveParam (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:120:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:135:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:61:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:88:9)
    at C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:56:13
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (C:\Users\app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:55:9)
```

If i change the code like this, its working fine

```
private readonly s3: S3
constructor() {
    this.s3 =  new S3();
}
```

Actually what is the problem here?
Is this is the right coding standard?

Expecting a valuable feedback

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is in the line `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AWSService `. You have `s3` as a dependency of `AWSService`. Since s3 is not injected then Nest has no way of resolving it. That's why initialising s3 in the constructor works. Basically, Nest can't pass the s3 argument in the constructor. You could try initialising s3 somewhere else in the application and then binding it to the context, that way you can inject it into `AWSService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like that `S3` was not registered as a provider in your `AWSModule` module. Thus, nestjs doesn't knows what it is.

You could use [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#custom-providers) like this:

1. `{ provide: S3, useValue: new S3() }`
2. `{ provide: S3, useFactory: () => new S3() }` -- in this case you can inject things on it. Read the docs.